# How to modify font-size in .resx values in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, resx

I'm still learning about Xamarin. I would like to ask if how can I modify the font-size being outputted from the string in my .resx file. I am using VS 2015, Xamarin Shared. Below are some of my contents in my .resx file.

```
    <data name="ERR_GENERAL_SERVER_ERROR_AUDIT" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Ensure that the tablet is within WiFi coverage and try again. 

If within WiFi coverage please follow the below steps:
    1. Force Close WISview
        • WIS Issued Device: Click the circle at the bottom of the tablet and then click "Clear all processes"
        • Non WIS Issued Device: Click the square at the bottom of the device and then clicking the X on the WISview tile
    2. Re-open WISview and select “no” to the screen that prompts you to “use this inventory”
    3. Re-print a new Inventory Control barcode from the Laptop
    4. Scan the newly printed Inventory Control Barcode.

If still unable to begin audit of tag {0}, please contact helpline.</value>
    <comment>Error</comment>
  </data>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also store numbers in resource files.

```
<data name="NotesLabel" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Notes:</value>
    <comment>label for input field</comment>
</data>

<data name="NotesLabelFontSize" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>15</value>
</data>
```

This code might not 100% run. But should give you the idea:

```
enter code here
var myLabel = new Label ();

// populate UI with translated text values from resources
myLabel.Text = AppResources.NotesLabel;
myLabel.FontSize = Convert.ToInt64(AppResources.NotesLabelFontSize);
```